# How do I replace entity references with character references?

Tags: html, ruby-on-rails, ruby

I'm looking for a way in Ruby or Rails to replace entity references (`&nbsp;`) in a file with their character reference equivalents (`&#160;`).

`&nbsp;` is the main offender, but I'd like to do the replacement systematically rather than just hand coding a bunch of gsubs.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the HtmlEntities gem:

```
gem install htmlentieties

require 'htmlentities'
decoded = HTMLEntities.new.decode '&nbsp;Hello'
decoded[0].ord       #=> 160
```

---

As Stefan mentioned in the comment, if you want to encode it back using reference numbers, just decode the string and encode it with the `:decimal` flag:

```
require 'htmlentities'
text = '&nbsp;Hello'
coder = HTMLEntities.new
final_text = coder.encode coder.decode('&nbsp;Hello'), :decimal
p final_text     #=> &#160;Hello
```

Comment: I think the OP wants to re-encode the entity: `HTMLEntities.new.encode(decoded, :decimal) #=> "&#160;"`

Comment: You might want to test your second solution code. It won't work.

Comment: @theTinMan - I have tested the code, it works for me. What error did you get? (Oh geez, there is a dot instead of coma. Sorted now)

Comment: `final_text` != `fianl_text`. When adding sample code it's a good idea to copy/paste it directly.

Comment: @theTinMan - true to that, I did copy paste everything except for the last line (as I will see the results from the previous line as well). Would be nice if you could fix the obvious typo when you saw it though. Corrected now.

Comment: I don't fix people's submitted code. That's considered bad form.

Answer (score 0):

```
"Max&nbsp;Williams".html_safe => "Max Williams"
```

This is functionality of Rails's Active Support.

Comment: That has apparently converted `&nbsp;` to `"\x20"` (regular space, raw character) and OP needs `"&#160;"` (non-breaking space, escaped using Unicode character number)